# Enlighten me with discordpy modals. They are not sending as views or any other way

Tags: discord, discord.py, modal-dialog

```
class VerifyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title="Verify"):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(timeout=None)
      self.username = discord.ui.TextInput(label="Fortnite Username", placeholder="Ninja...", required=True)


@bot.command()
async def verify_embed(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(
      title="Verify",
      color=discord.Color.green()
  )
  embed.add_field(name="How Do I Verify?", value="To Verify Please Click The Button below!", inline=False)

  verify_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Verify", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="verify", emoji="✅")

  async def verify_button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
      view = VerifyModal()
      await ctx.send("Please fill in the form to verify", view=view)

  verify_button.callback = verify_button_callback
  button = discord.ui.View()
  button.add_item(verify_button)

  message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=button)
```

I asked chatgpt (they were no help) then i went through the modal info page on discord.py (found nothing) js need someone with a bit more experience to help me

Comment: what's it sending tho? nothing? just the embed?

Comment: just the embed my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a modal as a view, you need to use the `interaction` object that you get in your button callback function, and use the `interaction.response.send_modal` function. Also you need to change your `VerifyModal` class, the `TextInput` should be a *class* variable not an *instance* variable.

Fixed code:

```py
class VerifyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title="Verify"):
    username = discord.ui.TextInput(label="Fortnite Username", placeholder="Ninja...", required=True)


@bot.command()
async def verify_embed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Verify",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
    embed.add_field(name="How Do I Verify?", value="To Verify Please Click The Button below!", inline=False)

    verify_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Verify", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="verify", emoji="✅")

    async def verify_button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(VerifyModal())

    verify_button.callback = verify_button_callback
    button = discord.ui.View()
    button.add_item(verify_button)

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=button)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Łukasz Kwieciński said, you can't use a modal as a view and you should use `await interaction.response.send_modal(VerifyModal())`. One thing I would add is that the callback of the modal should be provided in the `async def on_submit(interaction:discord.Interaction)` method of the modal. Your code would be:

```py
class VerifyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title="Verify"):
    username = discord.ui.TextInput(label="Fortnite Username", placeholder="Ninja...", required=True)
    async def on_submit(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        ... # whatever the callback is


@bot.command()
async def verify_embed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Verify",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
    embed.add_field(name="How Do I Verify?", value="To Verify Please Click The Button below!", inline=False)

    verify_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Verify", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="verify", emoji="✅")

    async def verify_button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(VerifyModal())

    verify_button.callback = verify_button_callback
    button = discord.ui.View()
    button.add_item(verify_button)

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=button)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the easiest way to create modals is to just use Classes

```
import discord
from discord import ui
from discord.ui import Button, View
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

The second package is for creating the Modal class and the third is to create a way to the modal.

```
class Register(ui.Modal, title='Create new account'):
first_name = ui.TextInput(label='First name',required=True,style=discord.TextStyle.short)
async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Thanks for your response, {self.first_name}!', ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def modal(ctx):
    view = View()
    modalButton = Button(label="Show Modal")
    async def modalButtonClicked(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(Register())
    modalButton.callback = modalButtonClicked
    view.add_item(modalButton)
    await ctx.reply("Hello",view=view)
```

This is just an example of a simple modal which lets you input a short text and it'll return it to you in the following message.

let me know if this helped!